# Почему шаблонная функция вызывается первой? C++

Tags: c++, строки, функции, шаблоны-с++

Насколько мне известно, когда мы создаем шаблонную функцию с шаблонными параметрами и частичную(к примеру которая принимает int) с одинаковыми именами то в случае вызова функции сначала должна вызваться более частная. Но почему это не работает со строками? Код:

```
#include <iostream>
 template <typename T>

 T foo(T, T) {
     return "not strings";
 }

 std::string foo(std::string, std::string) {
     return "strings";
 }    

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo("str", "str") << std::endl;
}
```

Почему здесь вызывается шаблонная функция? А с остальными типами данных вызывается более частная?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что вы передаете аргументы `"str"` — а они имеют тип не `string`, а `const char[4]`, так что для нешаблонной функции требуется дополнительное преобразование типов, а для шаблонной — нет.

```
foo("str"s, "str"s)
```

Можно попробовать так, можно

```
foo(string("str"), string("str"))
```